# Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: can't create directory on upgrading Magento from 1.9.2 to 2.0.0

Tags: upgrade, fatal-error, ce-1.9.2.0, magento-2.0

When I tried to upgrade Magento from 1.9.2 to 2.0.0 got the following error

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException' with message 'Can't create directory vendor/magento/framework/Code/Generator.php on line 103

Please could anyone help me solve this issue?

Comment: Toss out a good portion of what you know about Mage 1.x, don't be committing this on your live ecommerce server, you will be committing seppuku before the night's through.

Comment: That, Sir, is the most precise answer ever for "upgrading from 1.9 to 2.0"!!! Thank you for lightening up my day :) (I'm serious!)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Make read/write permission for var directory. That means var directory should be 0777.

Comment: Does it include All Sub Folder of `var` to 777 permission?

Answer (score 4):

Giving full permission (777) to var and pub directory after upgrade

Run below commands.

```
php bin/magento setup:upgrade

chmod -R 777 var pub
```

clear cache.

```
rm -rf var/cache/* var/generation/*
```

Answer (score 3):

Also getting error

> unable to create directory inside var directory

during installation of magento 2. It was because I have given 755 permissions to var folder. Changing it 777 worked like a charm.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to **upgrade** Magento 1.x to Magento 2.
It is possible to **migrate data** from an existing Magento 1.x shop to a new Magento 2 shop.
There is the official data migration tool: https://github.com/magento/data-migration-tool-ce

Comment: Hello @Mage2.PRO, can i get help regard Magento 2.3 installation error like [ERROR] RuntimeException: The path "C:/wamp/www/giri/generated/code/Magento/Directory/Helper/Data/Proxy.php.2984" cannot be renamed into "C:/wamp/www/giri/generated/code/Magento/Directory/Helper/Data/Proxy.php"   how can i solve this error?

Answer (score 2):

`var/generation` folder has been renamed to `generated/code` in Magento 2.2

So make sure to set permission to that folder.

```
chmod -R -v 777 generated/
```

Comment: This really help me sort a problem out.  We were implementing a new template on 2.2.5 and it involved updating and compiling.  After doing this with no errors visible whilst executing we were getting 500 errors accessing the site.  Added the error output and found it could not write a swatch the generated set of folders. Changed as per your instructions and works perfectly now! Thanks anyway as not related to the post but obviously works for other errors - noted it does not mention this in the Magento instructions unless I missed it?

Answer (score 0):

Please change the generation folder rewrite permission. Thats work for me.

```
sudo chmod -R 777  var/*
```